# How to extract the images from a wolfram list to an array/list of byte arrays using JLink in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code in Java, where I am trying to use the WolframAlpha command and get the result as a list of images (byte arrays)

```
String expr = "WolframAlpha[\"solve x^2+2x+1=0\", \"PodImages\", IncludePods->\"Result\", PodStates->\"Step-by-step solution\"]"
mathLink.evaluate(expr)
```

Evaluating the expression in a terminal gives me something like this. Using the Export function, I've seen the 2 images and they look right.

```
In[6]:= WolframAlpha["solve x^2+2x+1=0","PodImages", IncludePods->"Result", PodStates->"Step-by-step solution"]                                                 

Out[6]= {-Image-, -Image-}
```

I've tried to get the result as a byte[][] (`mathLink.getByteArray2()`), but I get the `MLGet out of sequence` exception, so I assumed the result I got wasn't an array of byte arrays.

I also tried getting the result as an Object, but I got the error that `Expression on link is not a valid Java object reference`

Doing `mathLink.getType()` told me that the result that I'm getting is a `MTFUNCTION`, so I tried reading the result as a function. Investigating further, I found out that the function type was `List` with 2 arguments. I'm assuming that those 2 arguments are the 2 images I want to get.

So my question is: How can I extract the images from the result as an array or list in Java?

Sorry if this is a silly question - I'm new to using JLink and the Wolfram Language

EDIT

In case this helps anyone, I tried logging the output from `mathLink.getExpr().toString()` and got:

```
{
    Image[
        NumericArray[
            {{
                {255, 255, 255}, {255, 255, 255}, ...more of these
            }}, 
            "UnsignedInteger8"
        ], 
        "Byte", 
        Rule[ColorSpace, "RGB"], 
        Rule[ImageSize, Automatic], 
        Rule[Interleaving, True], 
        Rule[Magnification, 1]
    ],
    Image[
        ...more of the same as above
    ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I can't check it right now, but you're getting image object, not array of bytes from Mathematica (btw providing the full code you use could help) as a result of evaluate.

To extract image data you can use `ImageData` (and in case of list of  images — `Map` over it), something like:

Comment: 2:   (this will give you a list of two arrays:
```
WolframAlpha["solve x^2+2x+1=0", "PodImages", IncludePods -> "Result",
    PodStates -> "Step-by-step solution"] // 
  Map[ImageData[#, Byte, Interleaving -> True] &] // Map[Dimensions]
```
basically what math link tells you're trying to read expression (which is not an array) as an array